# How to make Title Centered Dynamically in the complete center of page

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to find out how to make the title be completely centered on my [webpage](http://themightycraken.github.io/) both vertically and horizontally on all webpages/not dependent on the screen size. I am currently using `<br>` tags.

Here is what I want it to look like

[image: Here]

but when resized, I want it to change font size and stay centered.

Comment: The link to your webpage doesn't seem to have any connection with what you have written. Can you elaborate?  Also where is the code that you want us to look at?  It should be pasted into your question so it's here for future users to see too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use viewport units.

```
<h1 style="font-size: 30vh;"> Zakaria Ridouh </h1>
```

Ref: https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the help, im going to start using this version from now on :)

Answer (score 0):

U can try this one:

Remove `Width:50%;`

```
#intro

    color: white;
    /* width: 50%; */Remove this one
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Awesome, this actually helped!

Comment: It's Okay Sir @ZakariaRidouh

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the font size of Zakaria Ridouh text it will automatically set in that viewport like

```
<h1 style="font-size: 30em;"> Zakaria Ridouh </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center an element both vertically and horizontally, try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>title here</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #fafafa;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamster/3ugqwkn0/3/)